# Laravel On Demand Notification error "Undefined index: name"

Tags: php, laravel, undefined

Laravel 5.5.28

I'm using a Laravel's On Demand Notification to send out an email of a simple form submission to a central address.  I have followed the laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#on-demand-notifications)

I have mailtrap set up in the env file.

The code in my controller:

```
use Notification // set at top of class
$submission = FormSubmission::create($request->all());

Notification::route('mail', 'test@test.org')
    ->notify(new FormSubmissionNotificiation($submission));
```

but get a whoops error.  It fails on the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php` in this method

```
protected function setGlobalAddress($mailer, array $config, $type)
    {
        $address = Arr::get($config, $type);

        if (is_array($address) && isset($address['address'])) {
            $mailer->{'always'.Str::studly($type)}($address['address'], $address['name']);
        }
    }
```

where it's trying to find the `$address['name']` index.  But I don't have a name, and if I did, where do I put it?

Can't seem to figure it out, any help appreciated.

EDIT:
I've tried this a different way. I added in a user to my database, and added the `Notifiable` trait onto the `User` model and attempted to send out a notification like

`$user->notify(new FormSubmissionNotification($submission);` and still got the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: If you don't have a name, then take it out, and put `null` or `''` to pass in an empty string.

Comment: Take it out of where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.  Pretty stupid actually.

I added in a `MAIL_TO_ADDRESS` variable to my .env file to hold the email address I wanted to send the notifications to, but didn't want to call the env file directly in the controller so set up a new array element in the `config/mail.php` file like this

```
 'to' => [
      'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS')
  ],
```

Then I planned to use that in the controller like this

```
Notification::route('mail', config('mail.to.address'))
        ->notify(new FormSubmissionNotificiation($submission));
```

But even while I was testing using a dummy email address in a string directly in the controller, it was using that `to` variable with the email address from the mail config file.  Even though I wasn't referencing it anywhere.

Once I deleted that whole array from the config it worked, and similarly, if I add in a name to that array, it works.  That also stopped me using the standard `$user->notify()` as well and was always trying to use the email address from the env file rather than the User model.

Answer (score 0):

From [the notifications docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#mail-notifications):

> When sending mail notifications, be sure to set the `name` value in your  `config/app.php` configuration file. This value will be used in the header and footer of your mail notification messages.

Comment: Yes, this has a value already `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),`  I have a value for it in my env file.

Comment: @JohnHalsey try to put `dd($config, $type)` to the `setGlobalAddress()` method to see what exactly config Laravel tried to use. Also, if you removed this value recently, try to clear config cache with `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @alexey-mezenis goof idea thanks, it dumps the `$config` object and the type `mail` which looks fine.  I also dumped `$address` in there and it is an array with both `address` and `name` keys set with values.

Comment: @JohnHalsey what exactly does `dd($config, $type)` show?

Comment: OK, i loops over a few times before it breaks.  It loops over `from` and `reply_to` but breaks on `to`
```

Comment: It's too long to post into a comment.   But it loops over `from` and `reply_to` as the 'type' without problem, but breaks on `to`.  The `to` array has just the address in it, no name which is obviously why it breaks.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @JohnHalsey please show the `FormSubmissionNotificiation` class.

Comment: Hi @alexey-mezenin I'm pretty sure this is a bug.  I've written notifications many times, it looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

You must set    `MAIL_NAME` in `.env`

In `config/mail.php`

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM', null), 'name' => env('MAIL_NAME', null)],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#writing-mailables

Answer (score 0):

You have to put name  inside 'to' array In config\mail.php

```
to' => [
            'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
     ],
```

and in respective model

```
public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
          {
                return $this->email_address=config('mail.to.address');
           
          }
```

see laravel official doc [laravel@8.x](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait)